# Maven2 tools maven version

Tags: eclipse, maven

I have changed maven version by changing path variable to point to 2.2.1 but when I run maven2 tools from eclipse it uses maven version 3. How to change maven2 tools configuration. I doubt that maven2 tools comes with inbuilt maven.

Thanks,
Sriram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse has its own embedded Maven. To point to your local installation goto `Right Click Project --> Run As --> Run Configurations` You can see `Maven Runtime` here. Click `Configure` and add your local maven runtime.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to make sure that your required version of Maven is always invoked by default, is to add the version under Window -> Preferences -> Maven Installations and check the box to make it the default version.